# Object moves faster going in the diagonal

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a little player script by myself to make my player move, but I wanted the speed to be cut in half when he is moving in the diagonal because it has double the value of whenever he is going in a straight line. How would that be possible?

```
void Update()
    {
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime );
        gameObject.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position + direction;  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I wanted the speed to be cut in half when he is moving in the diagonal because it has double the value of whenever he is going in a straight line

No, actually it will be up to times `√(2)` ;)

You want to be using [`Vector3.ClampMagnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ClampMagnitude.html) in order to always have a maximum magnitude of `1f` for your input:

```
void Update()
{
    var input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    gameObject.transform.position += Vector3.ClampMagnitude(direction, 1f) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;  
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you, that's perfectly what I wanted.